# How to set default value in AppCompactSpinner using xml and databinding?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-appcompat

I want to use AppCompactSprinner inside recycler view, in the cell, I capture the response from AppCompactSpinner but once I scroll and the cell goes out of focus, values reset, is there a way to set default value using XML and data binding, my cell layout looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="obj"
            type="com.example.SpinnerCell" />

        <variable
            name="lis"
            type="com.example.CustomSpinnerListener" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/four_dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/four_dp"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/four_dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/four_dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:labelFor="@+id/spinner"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="@{obj.question}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/spinner"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@{obj.options}"
            android:onItemSelected="@{(parent,view,pos,id)->lis.onSpinnerItemSelected(parent,view,pos,id, obj)}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```